# Junit verify method never runs passing when it should fail

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have this unit test:

```
@RunWith (MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RefChangEventTest {
    @Mock
    RefChange ref;

    @Mock
    SEPCommits sepCommits;

    @Mock
    SEPRefChangeEvent sepRefChangeEvent;

    @Mock
    RepositoryRefsChangedEvent refsChangedEvent;

    @Mock
    Repository repo;

    @Test
    public void gitNotesAreIgnored() throws Exception {
        Collection<RefChange> refList = new ArrayList<RefChange>(1);
        ArrayList commitListMock = mock(ArrayList.class);
        refList.add(ref);
        when(refsChangedEvent.getRefChanges()).thenReturn(refList);
        when(refsChangedEvent.getRepository()).thenReturn(repo);
        when(ref.getRefId()).thenReturn("refs/heads/foo");
        when(sepRefChangeEvent.makeArrayList()).thenReturn(commitListMock);

        sepRefChangeEvent.processEvent(refsChangedEvent);
        verify(sepCommits, never()).findCommitInfo(ref, repo, commitListMock);
    }

}
```

and the source code to match it is here:

```
public ArrayList<Message> makeArrayList() {
    return new ArrayList<Message>();
}

@Override
public List<Message> processEvent(RepositoryRefsChangedEvent event) {
    ArrayList<Message> commitList = makeArrayList();

    for (RefChange refChange : event.getRefChanges()) {
        LOGGER.info("checking ref change refId={} fromHash={} toHash={} type={}", refChange.getRefId(), refChange.getFromHash(),
                refChange.getToHash(), refChange.getType());

        if (refChange.getRefId().startsWith(REF_BRANCH)) {
            if (refChange.getType() == RefChangeType.ADD && isDeleted(refChange)) {
                LOGGER.info("Deleted a ref that never existed. This shouldn't ever occur.");
            }
            else if (isDeleted(refChange) || isCreated(refChange)) {
                branchCreation(refChange, event.getRepository(), commitList);
            }
            else {
                sepCommits.findCommitInfo(refChange, event.getRepository(), commitList);
            }
        }
        else {
            LOGGER.info("This type of refChange is not supported.\n refId={} fromHash={} toHash={} type={}", refChange.getRefId(), refChange.getFromHash(),
                    refChange.getToHash(), refChange.getType());
        }
    }
    return commitList;
}
```

The test I have written should fail. The refID is `refs/heads/foo` and that should invoke the method that I'm testing should never be called. But, when I run this test, it passes with flying colors. Where am I messing up?

Yes I know PowerMockito can mock constructors, I made the simple `makeArrayList()` method to quickly write this unit test.

Comment: Post the entire class please. What I see is that you never set the class fields from the test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing a method call on sepRefChangeEvent which you have mocked, and mocked objects do nothing without a when...then or do...when instruction.

You should use Mockito.spy instead of mock on the object of SEPRefChangeEvent if you want to mock some methods but test the real implementation of other methods.

There are a number of ways to approach it, but you need to ensure that you are testing the real method and not a mocked version.

The choices include:

- Inject mocks into the real test subjet
- Use a spy on the test subject
- Use when(...).thenCallRealMethod().

The approach will depend on the complexity of the process you are testing.

Comment: Could an alternative be to mock all the items needed by the constructor and call the constructor to create a real SEPRefChangeEvent object?

Comment: Yes, there are a number of ways to approach it, but you need to ensure that you are testing the real method and not a mocked version. The choices include 1. Inject mocks into the real test subjet 2. Use a spy 3. Use when(...).thenCallRealMethod(). The approach will depend on the complexity of the process you are testing.